# How to lock a perforce branch

Tags: perforce

I am just assuming that simple lock on the branch will lock the branch ?  . will that suffice

Or is there any other special procedure to lock the branch . Please let me know if I need

Anything to do apart from just click on lock .

Comment: Where do you "just click on lock" ?
What do you mean by "lock" ? Protection against write access? Or against read access? Or exclusive access?

Comment: Added an answer though with the question content it was necessarily vague.  If you can provide a more focused question I can give a more precise answer...probably.

Answer (score 1):

The owner, admins, and superusers can lock *Streams* in Perforce with a button click yes.  When modifying a stream there is a box under the advanced tab:  "Locked (only the stream owner can edit stream settings)" and another:  "Submitting files to the stream restricted to stream owner"
Ok so its two clicks...these two combined effectively lock a stream for all other users.

I believe the only way to "lock" a branch in Perforce would be via the Permissions Table.  This can be viewed via the admin gui (separate install) or via `p4 protect` on the command line.  p4 protect is an admin/super user only item I believe